# Shiro grails plugin - config

Tags: grails, shiro

setting up shiro session cache with ehcache+terracotta  ,putitng these configs in config.groovy -

security.shiro.sessionDAO = "org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO"

// This name matches a cache name in ehcache.xml:
security.shiro.sessionDAO.activeSessionsCacheName = "shiro-activeSessionsCache"
security.shiro.securityManager.sessionManager.sessionDAO = "org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO"

// Configure The EhCacheManager:
security.shiro.cacheManager = "org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager"
security.shiro.cacheManager.cacheManagerConfigFile = "classpath:session_ehcache.xml"

// Configure the above CacheManager on Shiro's SecurityManager
// to use it for all of Shiro's caching needs:
security.shiro.securityManager.cacheManager = "org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager"

but looks like shiro plugin is not reading configurations, have used "security.shiro" as prefix

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out this could be done either of one way  -

1.Configure (override over plugin definition) proper shiroSecurityManager bean at `resources.groovy`:

```
myShiroSessionDAO(org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO) {
    activeSessionsCacheName="shiro-activeSessionsCache"
}
myShiroSessionManager(org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager) {
    sessionDAO = ref("myShiroSessionDAO")
}
myShiroCacheManager(org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager) {
    cacheManagerConfigFile = "classpath:session_ehcache.xml"
   //cacheManager = CacheManager.create()
}
shiroSecurityManager(org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager) {
    cacheManager = ref("myShiroCacheManager")
    sessionManager = ref("myShiroSessionManager")
}
```

OR

2.Configure shiroSecurityManager at `Bootstrap.groovy`

```
def sessionDao = new org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO()
sessionDao.activeSessionsCacheName="shiro-activeSessionCache"
shiroSecurityManager.sessionManager.sessionDAO = sessionDao
def cacheManager = new org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager()
cacheManager.cacheManagerConfigFile = "classpath:session_ehcache.xml"
shiroSecurityManager.cacheManager = cacheManager
```

@`Config.groovy` put -

```
security.shiro.session.mode="native"
```