# How to configure grails and shiro to mark cookies secure?

Tags: security, grails, session-cookies, shiro

I'm using Grails 2.2.4 with the Shiro plugin 1.1.4 and would like to mark the cookies as secure so the session information won't be sent over http.

I'm looking for the grails way to set this setting, which normally would be in shiro.ini

`securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.secure = true`

Open JIRA issue to track this: 
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSHIRO-76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the templates in your application if you don't already have them.   `grails install-templates`
2. Edit `src/templates/war/web.xml` so that it has session-config with cookie-config in it:

```
    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to patch sessionCookieConfig off of the servletContext in BootStrap:

```
class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        servletContext.sessionCookieConfig.secure = true
    }
}
```

Note: The option causes grails 2.2.4 integration tests to fail with an AbstractMethodError.

```
 Error Error executing script TestApp: org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig; 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:44)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
        ...
```

Comment: Note that SessionCookieConfig is available in servlet version 3.0

Answer (score 2):

You can set this through the `shiroSecurityManager` bean.  For example, in BootStrap:

```
def shiroSecurityManager

def init = { servletContext ->
    shiroSecurityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.secure = true
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it produced an error: `Message: No such property: sessionIdCookie for class: org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.ServletContainerSessionManager`

Comment: Ok, I think you need to override the type of the session manager.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633910/shiro-grails-plugin-config

Answer (score 1):

You can put your ini settings in the following block
In Config.groovy:

```
   security {
     shiro {
        filter.config = """
                       [main]your ini settings
                       [urls]your ini settings 
                       """
     }
   }
```